# PyCharm Type-Hinting: __metaclass__ bug?

Tags: python, pycharm

```
class MetaProp(type):
    @property
    def value1(cls):
        """
        :rtype: str
        """
        return "A String"

class ClassProp(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaProp

    @property
    def value2(self):
        """
        :rtype: str
        """
        return "A String"


instance = ClassProp()

assert isinstance(ClassProp.value1, basestring)
assert isinstance(instance.value2, basestring)
assert ClassProp.value1 == instance.value2

def some_method(val):
    """
    :type val: str
    """
    print val

some_method(instance.value2)
some_method(ClassProp.value1)
```

PyCharm gives me a warning on the last line, because "value1" is supposedly a property and not a string:

[image: screenshot]

The code works... Is this a bug in PyCharm, or is it something I'm missing?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15595